# Need to get difference between these two as output

Tags: sql, oracle

REQUIRED QUERY :

select all memberid from query 1 having higher count than query 2

the aim is to display all memberid who were leader/organiser/helper more times than they participate in event

how do i join these two select statement and view the required output

```
SELECT memberID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT memberID FROM leader UNION ALL
        SELECT memberID FROM organiser UNION ALL
        SELECT memberID FROM helper
    ) t
    GROUP BY memberID;
```

=============

```
select memberid,count(*) as cnt2
from eventmember group by memberid;
```

=======

Comment: Why haven't you accepted any of the answers in [your identical previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237639/need-to-build-query)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another, "all_in_one" solution

```
select
    memberid,
    count(*) as total_cnt,
    sum(case when type = 'eventmember' then 1 else 0 end) as eventmember_cnt,
    sum(case when type = 'eventmember' then 0 else 1 end) as other_cnt
from
    (   select memberid, 'leader' as type
        from leader union all

        select memberid, 'organiser' as type
        from organiser union all

        select memberid, 'helper' as type
        from helper union all

        select memberid, 'eventmember' as type
        from eventmember
    ) t
group by
    memberid
having
    sum(case when type = 'eventmember' then 1 else 0 end)
    < sum(case when type = 'eventmember' then 0 else 1 end)
```

Comment: hi tried this, but getting error ORA-00904: "OTHER_CNT": invalid identifier

Comment: edited the answer, you should use your aggregations instead of their aliases in Oracle

Comment: thanks !changed to my aggregations, but getting ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 5

Comment: did you do exactly the same query as in my edited answer?

Comment: `Error at Line: 2 Column: 5` looks like you have trouble with something in "select" block

Comment: try replacing `group by 1` with `group by member`

Comment: thanks a lot buddy !! it was a group by error... shoud have used group by
    1, memberid - it works now..

Comment: hi i still have a dout regarding same query , but need to share screenshot to clear it to u - is there any option to message here( im new here)

Comment: I'm new too, so my only advise is to create external link for screenshot and post it here

Comment: @ShyamChandran - the privilege to post embed images is restricted to site users with at least 10 rep [to prevent abuse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268475/146325). You have sufficient rep so you should be able to post a screenshot. However, please consider whether it's truly necessary. Text is more readable and more useful in many cases (not least cut'n'paste).

Answer (score 0):

try like below using cte

```
  with cte as
    (
    SELECT memberID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM
        (
            SELECT memberID FROM leader UNION ALL
            SELECT memberID FROM organiser UNION ALL
            SELECT memberID FROM helper
        ) t
        GROUP BY memberID
    ),cte1 as
   (
   select memberid,count(*) as cnt2
   from eventmember group by memberid
  ) select cte.memberID,cnt,cnt2 from cte join ct1 on cte.memberID=cte1.memberid
```

Comment: ORA-00904: "CTN2": invalid identifier

Comment: yes, figured it out.. but the result i get  does not answer the requirement. i want memberid from orfaniser/helper/leader whose  count > that. of eventmember table.. plz refer to  question

Comment: @ShyamChandran your question was how would you join 2 query , so i think my answer cover that one if you need any others then ask in separate question